# Differences between makefile() and send() recv() Python

Tags: python, sockets

Whats the purporse of using makefile() when working with Python Sockets??

I can make a program works just with send() and recv() functions on Python. But i read that is better to use the makefile() method to buffer the data. I didn't understand this relation and differences...any help?

Tks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `makefile` if you find the file interface of Python convenient. For example, you can then use methods like `readlines` on the socket (you'd have to implement it manually when using `recv`). This can be more convenient if sending text data on the socket, but YMMV.

Comment: So, saving the makefile() in a variable is the same as save the recv() result on a variable, except the fact that makefile() can be manipulated like a file (using readline() for examples) and do not have the bytes's limit like recv() does. Is that right??

Comment: @StarkBR: no. The result of `recv` is the bytes it received. The result of `makefile` is a file-like object you can `read` from, as well as use other methods of file objects. At this point it would be best to google a bit for `python socket makefile` and see some examples